# Help to identify SMD part

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Can anyone help to give any clues about identifying this part? It is from a Chinese guitar pedal and appears to be at the beginning of the input chain, so I would suspect perhaps some kind of op amp, but might be wrong. None of the markings seem to match any prefixes in the SMT codebook, etc. but I just wondered if it might happen to mean anything to someone with more experience.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a DIO2022 op-amp, [see datasheet](http://www.dioo.com/attachments/files/20161219154018_372.pdf). It looks like other manufacturers make op-amps with type code of 2022 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Putting part markings into a search engine can quite often solve this type of question pretty quickly.

This is a [DIO2022](http://www.dioo.com/attachments/files/20161219154018_372.pdf) from [Dioo Microcircuits](http://www.dioo.com/products/detail/id/86.html).

Seems like a pretty generic op amp.

I've never heard of the manufacturer before, but they seem to be based in and primarily do business in China, which would make sense as you say this is from a Chinese device.

Comment: Thanks that's got it. I feel a bit dumb as I spent a long time searching for D10...(D one zero), but not DIO (the letters), so useful to know for the future.

Comment: @Duntle Part numbers are very commonly two or three letters followed by three or four numbers, which is a good rule of thumb to keep in mind.

Comment: In this case there is also a 1 on the date code which is clearly different from the I.